# Fail to convert Caffe model to Core ML model

Tags: caffe, coreml, coremltools

When I try to convert a model from Caffe to Core ML model with coremltools, I get the following:

```
================= Starting Conversion from Caffe to CoreML ======================
Layer 0: Type: 'Data', Name: 'data'. Output(s): 'data', 'label'.
WARNING: Skipping Data Layer 'data' of type 'Data'. It is recommended to use Input layer for deployment.
Layer 1: Type: 'Split', Name: 'label_data_1_split'. Input(s): 'label'. Output(s): 'label_data_1_split_0', 'label_data_1_split_1'.
Layer 2: Type: 'Convolution', Name: 'conv1'. Input(s): 'data'. Output(s): 'conv1'.
Layer 3: Type: 'Slice', Name: 'slice1'. Input(s): 'conv1'. Output(s): 'slice1_1', 'slice1_2'.
Layer 4: Type: 'Eltwise', Name: 'etlwise1'. Input(s): 'slice1_1', 'slice1_2'. Output(s): 'eltwise1'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert('_iter_3560000.caffemodel')
  File "/Users/zfh/Desktop/face_verification_experiment/model/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/caffe/_caffe_converter.py", line 142, in convert
    predicted_feature_name)
  File "/Users/zfh/Desktop/face_verification_experiment/model/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/coremltools/converters/caffe/_caffe_converter.py", line 187, in _export
    predicted_feature_name
RuntimeError: Unsupported option 'Max' for the parameter 'operation' in layer 'etlwise1' of type 'Elementwise' during caffe conversion.
```

This is the code I am using:

```
import coremltools
coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('_iter_3560000.caffemodel', 'LCNN_deploy.prototxt'))

coreml_model.save('_iter_3560000.mlmodel')
```

Any ideas what the problem is? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the problem is that the Max operation in an Eltwise layer is not supported by the coremltools. Core ML only supports a limited number of layers.

However... it seems like maybe you're trying to convert the .prototxt that was used for training (even though the filename is `LCNN_deploy.prototxt`). Are you sure this is the correct deploy.prototxt?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, it is the correct deploy.prototxt. I assumed Core ML can support all Caffe models. If Core ML can only support a limited number of layers, I think it is more like a half-baked product.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the Core ML model specification _does_ have a MaxLayer which computes the elementwise maximum over the inputs. So in theory this should work. Maybe try writing `Max` as `MAX` in the prototxt (no idea if that makes a difference but usually I've seen the operation written in uppercase)?

Comment: @RobertHuang - Given how extensible Caffe is, and how new layer types are continually being added, I think it's reasonable to expect that only a subset of the most popular layer types will be supported in a version 1 API. This might be a great use of [a feature request](https://bugreport.apple.com), because [they're actively adding new layer types](https://twitter.com/bradlarson/status/890626062966595588) in the beta period.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans it is MAX in the prototxt. It cannot be changed to "Max" or "max". Once I changed it to something other than MAX, the tool outputted error.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I extract the convert tools of caffe2mlmodel from the coremltools, its the c++ implemention.
First of all，you need to know this tool supported caffe layer, defined in caffe.proto(include in caffeconverter directory)
And, then, open the caffe.proto, you can locate at the message LayerParameter, like below:,. You can find the supported caffe layer. 
[caffe.proto in caffeconverter of coremltools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btYE0.jpg)
Finally, if you want the custom caffe layer, just add adapt the caffe.proto , and learn the Core ML mode protobuf specification(https://apple.github.io/coremltools/coremlspecification/#)